# Add skype, linked, telephone and mail logos in cv

Tags: logos, fontawesome

I am trying to add logo in my CV using the package fontawesome. However it seems so complicated. I have read many forum, tried different types of compilation but I cannot include what I want, so I am asking if anyone can help me. I would like 4 logos:

For the phone: like a banana [image]
For the mail: letter
for skype
for linked

They should be included next to the positions where my personal informations are.

Can anyone provide me an answer. And if I have to install something, can you describe precisely how to install a package because it seems confused for me (should i use the terminal to type codes etc??)

Thanks a lot and have a nice evening

% PACKAGES
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.6cm, right=0.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}


% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{coolblack}}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}



% Title line color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{RGB}{58, 53, 61}

% Left margin
\reversemarginpar
\marginparwidth 96pt



% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}


% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\leavevmode
\marginpar{\normalsize\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
\ignorespaces}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}


% Personal informations and picture
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{cv_picture.jpg}}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\mymarginnote{\smash{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\textbf{Branch Warren}}}
\mbox{}

\mymarginnote{route 17 \\ aabama 76 \\ Switzerland \\     ++4176 67 34 56 \\ branchwarren} 
Born on the 2th of March  1887



US nationality

 Branchwarren@gmail.com

branchwarren

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want a banana http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm for a phone? ;-)

Comment: ahaha, it was just to give an idea, i included a picture to show you

Comment: A litle pet project of mine deals with stuff like that, it might suit you. https://github.com/johannesbottcher/bausteineBewerbung

Comment: It was certainly a joke, but the other two are really unclear for me. White S on a blue background for Skype or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the misprision, the logo from the fontawesome package would be awesome but I have many issues working with it

Comment: Johannes thanks for your answer. However, I am trying to avoid modern cv package. do you know another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy enough to do using fontawesome. Here I have compiled with XeLatex. I don't know what icons you want so I selected some random ones.

I decided not to use the fontawesome package - rather just download the font itself and put it in your project folder (named FontAwesome.otf) -- in fact here I have the font in a folder next to the project folder called code (move it and the relevant line as you wish). It has newer updated icons which will not be in the package. I created macros only for the glyphs you might need (it is obvious how to create more).

I didn't mess with the rest of your code (which is not optimal) apart from font related things (and removing soul which is not needed here). I made one glyph red just for fun.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10 pt, oneside, final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=4.6cm, right=0.75cm, top=0.5cm, bottom=0.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}%<added
\usepackage{libertine}%<added
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{marvosym}

%some Fontawesome stuff
\newfontfamily{\FA}[Path=../code/,Scale=.80]{FontAwesome.otf}
\def\fafacebooksq{{\FA \symbol{"F082}}}
\def\faphone{{\FA \symbol{"F095}}}
\def\faphonesq{{\FA \symbol{"F098}}}
\def\fatwitter{{\FA \symbol{"F099}}}
\def\fakeyboardo{{\FA \symbol{"F11C}}}

% Title format
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{} [{\color{coolblack}}\vskip-\topskip\rule{\linewidth}{0.8pt}]
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{0ex plus 0ex minus 0ex}{0ex plus 0ex}



% Title line color
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{RGB}{58, 53, 61}

% Left margin
\reversemarginpar
\marginparwidth 96pt



% DOCUMENT
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}


% Command label item
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\raise .5ex\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}
\newcommand{\mymarginnote}[1]{\leavevmode
\marginpar{\normalsize\textcolor{black}{#1}}%
\ignorespaces}


\setlength\parindent{0pt}


% Personal informations and picture
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{00mm}
    \hfill
    \fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{example-image-a}}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\mymarginnote{\smash{\fontsize{10.5}{12}\textbf{Branch Warren}}}
\mbox{}

\mymarginnote{\faphonesq~route 17 \\ aabama 76 \\ Switzerland \\\faphone~++4176 67 34 56 \\ branchwarren} 
Born on the 2th of March  1887

US nationality

\textcolor{red}{\fakeyboardo}~Branchwarren@gmail.com

\fatwitter~twitter

\fafacebooksq~facebook

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help and exercise. I really appreciate it. By the way you wrote that my code is not optimal, can you tell me why? It would help me improving my abilities in latex. Thank you again :)